# "Multipart: Boundary not found": File upload issue with Reactjs, Express, Multer and S3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image from my React frontend, but running into an Unprocessable Entity error. The server route works as I have successfully uploaded an image through Postman.

```
const handleFileUpload = async (file: any) => {
    const imageData = new FormData();
    imageData.append("image", file[0]);

    const config = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",

        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      body: imageData,
    };

    try {
      const req = await fetch(url, config);
      if (req.ok) {
        const res = await req.json();
        console.log(res);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Input:

```
<input
   type="file"
   accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
   onChange={(e: any) => { handleFileUpload(e.target.files ? e.target.files : url); }}
/>
```

Comment: try with "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", in my case worked this way.

Comment: With the new "Content-Type" I am now getting a 500 internal server error

Comment: Hmm.. Try checking the exact configuration you used in Postman, and use it here. That will be the right way for you. It depends on what code you have on the API too.

Comment: Does anything in the input, onChange or FormData look off?

Answer (score 1):

To solve, I removed the headers from the POST request so that fetch would automatically generate them. Server wise, I needed to set a limit on bodyParser to 50mb. Here are my edits:

```
const handleFileUpload = async (file: any) => {

    const imageData = new FormData();
    imageData.append("image", file);

    const config = {
      method: "POST",
      body: imageData,
    };

    try {
      const req = await fetch(url, config);
      if (req.ok) {
        const res = await req.json();
        console.log(res);
        if (res.success) {
          setURL(res.user.profilePicture);
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I'm glad you made it :)

Comment: getting 504 Gateway Time-out after removing header

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example:

```
// the input
<input
    type="file"
    accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/gif"
    className={classes.uploadInput}
    ref={ref => upload = ref}
    onChange={e => uploadAvatar(e.target.files[0])}
/>

// redux action
const uploadAvatar = avatar => ({type: ActionType.TRY_CHANGE_AVATAR, avatar})

// redux-saga

const data = new FormData()
data.append('avatar', avatar)

// axios request

const result = yield axios.post(API_LINK, data)

// in my php I have this headers

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// and 

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $uploadFolder . $filename))
...

// to upload it.
```

This is just an example not really an answer to your question, but still i hope this helps in some way.